# How to see everything in colour

Tags: vertex-paint

I draw colour on my mesh with vertex paint. I see colour on one piece of the mesh at a time in vertex paint mode. How do i see everything in colour in edit mode and sculpt mode?[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

At the top-right of the Viewport, click the dropdown arrow next to the Wireframe-Solid-Material-Rendered buttons and change the Color from "Material" to "Attribute".

[image]